# When I call a method not synchronized from a synchronized what appen?

Tags: java, multithreading

if I have two thread A and B that use the same class `C.java` what happens if thread A use a synchronized method(`synchro()`) that access use another class method(`myMethod()`) and after 1ms or minus thread B try to use `myMethod()`? He will wait until thread A has finished or it accesses to `myMethod()`? Thread A and Thread B use the same class instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Synchronization* is not *implicitly transitive*. It is merely a lock on the object to execute a block of code. It does not lock the objects that are used *inside* the code block.

Comment: The method that is synchronized is only one. To avoid that A and B try to access to the same method at the same can I use a Boolean with lock and unlock?

Comment: @user3897247 - that depends, is `myMethod()` *static*?.If yes, then you could lock the class object. If it is at instance level, you have to lock the *one* instance being used by both threads. Yes, you could also use a boolean flag with *volatile* modifier (busy waiting concept).

Answer (score 1):

Thread B will have access to the unsynchronized method. Since it's not synchronized, Thread B doesn't need to wait to acquire an object monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Implicit mutex lock will be introduced only for method `synchro()`, but not for `myMethod()`, since `myMethod()` is not synchronized. As a consequence access to `myMethod()` will not be syncronized between multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

It will access it.

Only synchronized methods or synchronized blocks cannot be executed concurrently: [Synchronized Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a synchronized method.

Repeat after me:  There is *no such thing* as a synchronized method.

When you write this:

```
synchronized Foobar myFunk() { ... }
```

That's just syntactic sugar that saves you from having to write this instead:

```
Foobar myFunk() {
    synchronized(this) { ... }
}
```

But the second one makes it more obvious what is really going on:  It's not the *method* that is synchronized, it's the *object*.

The JVM will not allow two different threads to synchronize the same object at the same time.  That's *all* it means.  Synchronizing an object does not "lock" the object (other threads can still modify it).  Synchronizing an object does not prevent other threads from calling the same method.  All it does is prevent other threads from synchronizing the same object at the same time.

How you use that feature is up to you.

Normally, you use it to protect *invariants*.  An invariant is an assertion that you make about some value or some *group* of values.  (e.g., the length of list L is always even).  If one thread must temporarily break the invariant (e.g., by first adding one thing to the list, and then adding another), and some other thread will crash and burn if it sees the broken invariant; then you need synchronization.

The first thread only breaks the invariant while inside a synchronized block, and any other thread only *looks* at the data when it is synchronized on the same object.  That way, the one the looks can never see the invariant in the broken state.